# query limit constraint propagation into subquery

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization, subquery-factoring

Here my streamlined situation

```
create table t1 (i integer, d text);
insert into t1 values (0,'aa0');
insert into t1 values (1,'aa1');
insert into t1 values (2,'aa2');
insert into t1 values (3,'aa3');
insert into t1 values (4,'aa4');
insert into t1 values (5,'aa5');
insert into t1 values (6,'aa6');
insert into t1 values (7,'aa7');
insert into t1 values (8,'aa8');
insert into t1 values (9,'aa9');

create table t2 (i integer, e text);
insert into t2 values (0,'aa0');
insert into t2 values (1,'ba1');
insert into t2 values (2,'aa2');
insert into t2 values (3,'ba3');
insert into t2 values (4,'aa4');
insert into t2 values (5,'ba5');
insert into t2 values (6,'aa6');
insert into t2 values (7,'ba7');
insert into t2 values (8,'aa8');
insert into t2 values (9,'ba9');
```

I then have an outer SELECT whose purpose is to print out the table t1 for a select list of ID (i)

```
select d from t1 where i in (3,4) limit 4;
d
----
aa3
aa4
```

The ID set is generated so I can end up with

```
select d from t1 where i in (3,4,1,6,7) limit 4;
d
----
aa1
aa3
aa4
aa6
```

Sometimes the ID set is the result of an inner SELECT subquery like this

```
select d from t1 where i in (select i from t2 where e>'b') limit 4;
d
----
aa1
aa3
aa5
aa7
```

In my real case t1 and t2 are big and the inner SELECT can generate a big ID list, that the outer select will nuke with its limit constraint.

My question is, does the query optimiser detect this outter limit constrainst and propagate it into the inner select?

If the answer is NO, then I should go the extra mile and my query generator, got to move the limit constraint explicitly in the inner SELECT like this

```
select d from t1 where i in (select i from t2 where e>'b' limit 4);
d
----
aa1
aa3
aa5
aa7
```

Before asking I looked EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN but this is beyond my knowledge and could not answer from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no [optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) that could move a LIMIT clause into a subquery, and subquery flattening does not apply to IN clauses.

This is confirmed with EXPLAIN (addr 22 is in the outer loop):

```
sqlite> explain select d from t1 where i in (select i from t2 where e>'b') limit 4;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     26    0                    00  Start at 26
1     Integer        4     1     0                    00  r[1]=4; LIMIT counter
2     OpenRead       0     2     0     2              00  root=2 iDb=0; t1
3     Rewind         0     24    0                    00
4       Noop           0     0     0                    00  begin IN expr
5       Once           0     16    0                    00
6       OpenEphemeral  3     1     0     k(1,B)         00  nColumn=1
7       OpenRead       1     3     0     2              00  root=3 iDb=0; t2
8       Rewind         1     15    0                    00
9         Column         1     1     2                    00  r[2]=t2.e
10        Le             3     14    2     (BINARY)       52  if r[3]<=r[2] goto 14
11        Column         1     0     4                    00  r[4]=t2.i
12        MakeRecord     4     1     5     C              00  r[5]=mkrec(r[4])
13        IdxInsert      3     5     0                    00  key=r[5]
14      Next           1     9     0                    01
15      Close          1     0     0                    00
16      Column         0     0     2                    00  r[2]=t1.i
17      IsNull         2     23    0                    00  if r[2]==NULL goto 23
18      Affinity       2     1     0     C              00  affinity(r[2])
19      NotFound       3     23    2     1              00  key=r[2]; end IN expr
20      Column         0     1     6                    00  r[6]=t1.d
21      ResultRow      6     1     0                    00  output=r[6]
22      DecrJumpZero   1     24    0                    00  if (--r[1])==0 goto 24
23    Next           0     4     0                    01
24    Close          0     0     0                    00
25    Halt           0     0     0                    00
26    Transaction    0     0     2     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
27    TableLock      0     2     0     t1             00  iDb=0 root=2 write=0
28    TableLock      0     3     0     t2             00  iDb=0 root=3 write=0
29    String8        0     3     0     b              00  r[3]='b'
30    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

---

Please note that LIMIT without an ORDER BY clause is probably not very useful, unless you actually want a random sample of rows.

Comment: Thanx CL for the prompt reply. I will take care of the LIMIT placement then. In my case the limit is just a way of validating a query. The order is not relevant, the selected ID's in the inner select are a regexp match, then the list is a list of match. It is a bit like "grep foo bifgile | head -4". I am not fluent in EXPLAIN yet, and didn't spotted the test as my real case is real big and there are many tests.

Comment: I should have used EXPLAIN on my tiny test here , sorry about that.

Comment: You are not really expected to understand the EXPLAIN output …